# Python file attachment error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add an email attachment in python, and I keep getting the error:

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/myname/Desktop/Current Desktop/Folder'

Here is my code:

```
file =  "myfile.pdf"
attachment = open("/Users/myname/Desktop/Current Desktop/Folder","rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=%s" % file)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is `/Users/myname/Desktop/Current Desktop/Folder` a directory? It seems like it is...

Comment: Looks likeyou are trying to attach a directory. you might want to zip or tarball  it first, and then attach..

Comment: it's a directory that contains the file -myfile.pdf- that i'm trying to attach. I was trying to write the file path for attachment. I guess i'm not understanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
with open("/Users/myname/Desktop/Current Desktop/Folder/" + "myfile.pdf", "rb") as file: 

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload(file.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=%s" % file)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a bunch! The only thing that needed to be changed is rb needs to be in quotes like so "rb". Other than that it worked flawlessly! I'll accept the answer when I can in 3 mins.

Comment: No problem! Easy fix. Thanks again!